# How to call custom web part's method in Ajax call?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, custom-web-parts, jquery-ajax

He I am trying to call one of my method in web part using ajax call but there I am getting error as

```
Test2.aspx/ReadData
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have declared method as like

```
 [WebMethod]
      [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static string ReadData(string year)
        {
            return year;
        }
    }
```

and using Ajax call as like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.LoadMore").click(function () {
        alert("callAjaxMethod");
       // var siteCollectionURL = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
        var loc = window.location.href;
        alert(loc);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test2.aspx/ReadData",

            data: {year: '2017' },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.d) {
                    alert("Success");

                }
                else {
                    alert("Failed");
                }
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failed");

            }
        });
        alert("After callAjaxMethod");
    });
});
```

Test2.aspx is my page name where i am adding that web part.
here i have tried url as

```
url: "Visualwebpart1.ascx.cs/ReadData",
```

but there also i am getting the same error.
Is there any way to get this work?

Comment: Instead of defining your WebMethod in WebPart, create an application page and define the WebMethod in that application page. Use the application page URL like `/_layouts/YourSolution/ApplicationPage.aspx/ReadData`

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.
why don't you post it as an Answer.

Comment: Posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining your WebMethod in WebPart, create an application page and define the WebMethod in that application page. Use the application page URL like `/_layouts/YourSolution/ApplicationPage.aspx/ReadData`